# curling http-server is ok but with the browser doesn't work

Tags: go, web-applications, ubuntu-18.04, simplehttpserver

I'm just approaching webapps in Golang.

This is the simple code as starting point:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

const (
        CONN_HOST = "localhost"
        CONN_PORT = "8080"
)

func helloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorld)
        err := http.ListenAndServe(CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT, nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("error starting http server : ", err)
                return
        }
}
```

Executing:

```
go run http-server.go

curl http://localhost:8080/
Hello World!
```

But when opening in a web-browser the ip-address:

```
http://111.111.1.1:8080/
connection didn't succeed
```

If I substitute this piece of code:

```
        err := http.ListenAndServe(CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT, nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("error starting http server : ", err)
                return
        }
```

with :

```
         log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

so the main() function is composed of just these 2 lines:

```
    func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorld)
    }

curl http://localhost:8080/
Hello World!
```

And in the web-browser:

```
http://111.111.1.1:8080/

Hello World!
```

So.... how to make the original simple http-server.go working in the web-browser and not only with commmand-line curl ?
Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: When you find that something works with one client and not another, the absolute first thing to do is triple-check that the requests you're making in each client are the same. In this case they clearly are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip address your server listened to is `localhost`，so it only handled requests to `localhost`.

You can try `curl http://111.111.1.1:8080/`， you would fail too.

If you want to access you server from lan or any other IP, you should set `CONN_HOST = "111.111.1.1"。`

Comment: Hi Billy. Putting const (
        CONN_HOST = "111.111.1.1:"
        CONN_PORT = "8080"
)               go run http-server.go
2019/01/25 16:19:11 error starting http server : listen tcp: address 111.111.1.1::8080: too many colons in address
exit status 1

Comment: I made a mistake. const (
        CONN_HOST = "111.111.1.1"
        CONN_PORT = "8080"
)
 Now. it works... thank you very much!!!!